# Mapping Images when an option is selected in DropDownMenu : JetPackCompose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making this app to display timetabe of diifferent branches of our colleges.
I've 2 images in drawable

Now I want to know how do I kind of Map the images, so when I click suppose "BMD", the timetable image is pulled from drawable and present right below "TimeTable:".

I also want the image to be click to enlarge, so i can zoom in and see all the details

```
@Composable
fun Timetable() {
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var inputBranch by remember { mutableStateOf("") }


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Branch : ")

        Row {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = inputBranch,
                onValueChange = { inputBranch = it },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                label = { Text(text = "Select Your Branch") }
            )
            TextButton(
                onClick = { showDialog = true }
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown, "")
            }

            DropdownMenu(expanded = showDialog, onDismissRequest = { showDialog = false })
            {
                DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("BMD")}, onClick = {
                    showDialog = false
                    inputBranch = "BMD"
                })

                DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("BT")}, onClick = {
                    showDialog = false
                    inputBranch = "BT"
                })

            }
        }
        Text("TimeTable : ")
    }
}
```

[My Drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2v82.png)
[Sample Timetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDDKA.png)

I searched theough internet, I found things like MAP{DS}, maybe SQL, but I want something that is easy to implement, easy to modify and not take storage permission from user